# Is Id necessary in applying jquery functions?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Suppose I have two `p` tags in the document. I want to call two different effects using **jQuery** when **onMouseOver** event happens. Is it necessary that these two `p` tags be given Ids. Can't it be achieved without giving Ids to these tags ?

Comment: See http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't **have** to give anything an `id`, however it is the best way to uniquely identify an element.

You can instead idenfity by class:

```
$(".myClass")
```

By attribute:

```
$("[src='image.jpg']")
```

By position in parent:

```
$("p:eq(2)")
```

A full list of selectors is available in the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/)

Comment: Thanks for replying !! Both 'p' tags are having same class. And I want to apply different functions when say click event occurs on the paragraphs. So for this I guess we need to give ids to both the paragraphs ?

Answer (score 5):

```
$('p:first'); // first p tag
$('p:last'); // last p tag
$('p').eq(1); // exactly the second p tag
```

Answer (score 3):

There are several ways to select an element / elements:

```
$('.classname')

$('#id')

$('tagname')

$('[attr="value"]')
```

etc

Answer (score 3):

although jQuery allows you to write faster and easier scripts, but unfortunately it makes you never understand the real JavaScript.

```
$("*") //selects all elements.

$(":animated") //selects all elements that are currently animated.

$(":button") //selects all button elements and input elements with type="button".

$(":odd") //selects even elements.

$(":odd") //selects odd elements.$("p") selects all <p> elements.

$("p.intro") //selects all <p> elements with class="intro".

$("p#intro") //selects the first <p> elements with id="intro".

$(this)     //Current HTML element
$("p#intro:first")  //The first <p> element with id="intro"
$("p:eq(2)")        // The third <p> element in the DOM
$(".intro")     //All elements with class="intro"
$("#intro")     //The first element with id="intro"
$("ul li:first")    //The first <li> element of the first <ul>
$("ul li:first-child")  //The first <li> element of every <ul>
$("[href]")     //All elements with an href attribute
$("[href$='.jpg']")     //All elements with an href attribute that ends with ".jpg"
$("[href='#']")     //All elements with an href value equal to "#"
$("[href!='#']")    //All elements with an href value NOT equal to "#"
$("div#intro .head")    //All elements with class="head" inside a <div> element with id="intro"
```

jQuery – Select element [cheat sheet](http://comp345.awardspace.com/select_element_cheatsheet.pdf)